# AWS Athena - Format and filter datetime

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table which is fed two different date formats:

d/m/Y & m/d/Y. The date format wanted is d/m/Y

I am able to select the date column and do a check and format if the date is in the wrong format.

This is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY(date_format(date_parse(tbl.date, %d/%m/%Y), %d/%m/%Y)),
                TRY(date_format(date_parse(tbl.date, %m/%d/%Y), %d/%m/%Y))) as date
FROM xxx
```

That fixes the mismatched dates...however I also need to query a date range e.g. the last 7 days.

If I add a WHERE statement it does not execute as I have already queried the date earlier.

How can I format my dates AND filter based on a given range (last 7 days)?

Answer (score 2):

In ANSI SQL -- implemented by Presto, which Athena is based on -- the `WHERE` clause cannot reference the `SELECT` projections, so you need a aubquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(TRY(date_parse ....... AS date
  FROM xxx
)
WHERE date > current_date - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

Comment: Everything works great until WHERE where I get: ">" cannot be applied to varchar, date. Any suggestions?